# Group by and sort in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a JSON data like below  stored in a mongodb collection

```json
{
    "name": "abc",
    "country": "xyz",
    "bloodGroup": "A+",
    "contact": "000001111"
}
```

I am trying to group by country **and** bloodGroup and sort the result in descending order.. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `$group` using two values as `_id` and `$sum` result. Then using `$sort` by the value you want using 1 or -1.

As [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) says:

- 1: Sort ascending.
- -1: Sort descending.

So you can use `-1`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "country": "$country",
        "bloodGroup": "$bloodGroup"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "count": -1
    }
  }
])
```

Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SqLqePy4FTC)

Comment: small query.. now in the result I want only top 5 rows..  if I add limit(5)..its not working.. any idea?  I want only top 5 rows

Comment: Try [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FxBBFRV-CQB) using 5 instead of 1.